# Long running job Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to create a web page which takes a string as an input and start a process. The process will run for long time. I need to email the results after processing. 
Which spring API should I use ?

The user will close the browser once he makes the request . I am a newbie to Java EE and spring . 
Can anyone say the architecture that is needed to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some executor service:

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService executorService() {
    return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

Then

```
executorService.execute(yourLongRunningTaskRunnable);
```

in your controller, where `yourLongRunningTaskRunnable` is, of course, a `Runnable`. This like schedules your task for execution. The task could send an email if needed in the end.

This is not a Spring API, but it seems suitable for such a task.